# Detect whether a gesture was clockwise or anticlockwise

Tags: android, gesture

I am using `OnGestureListener` in my class.
I want to find out the gesture done by me is clockwise or anticlockwise and want to perform different tasks on those gestures. Does `OnGestureListener` offer this feature? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See if this example helps you in any ways!

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/

Comment: No i am not getting it i am looking for vecotr multipication logic for detecting claock wise or anti clock wise logic

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(prediction.size() > 0){
  String gesturePerformed = prediction.get(0).name;
  if(gesturePerformed.equals("up")){
   myForeground.canvasUp();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else if(gesturePerformed.equals("down")){
   myForeground.canvasDown();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else if(gesturePerformed.equals("left")){
   myForeground.canvasLeft();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else if(gesturePerformed.equals("right")){
   myForeground.canvasRight();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else if(gesturePerformed.equals("clockwise")){
   myForeground.canvasClockwise();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "clockwise", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else if(gesturePerformed.equals("anti-clockwise")){
   myForeground.canvasAntiClockwise();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "anti-clockwise", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else if(gesturePerformed.equals("enlarge")){
   myForeground.canvasEnlarge();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "enlarge", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else if(gesturePerformed.equals("reduce")){
   myForeground.canvasReduce();
   Toast.makeText(MyGameActivity.this,
     "reduce", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }
```

}

Source:http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/03/gestures-detection-and-canvas-scale.html

Comment: No i am not getting it i am looking for vecotr multipication logic for detecting claock wise or anti clock wise logic